# есть варианты оптимизации такого запроса?

Tags: mysql

```
WHERE firm='Mersedes Benz' AND model='e320' AND body='221' AND ( kaywords LIKE
 '%1998%' OR kaywords LIKE '%1999%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2000%' OR kaywords LIKE
 '%2001%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2002%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2003%' OR kaywords LIKE 
 '%2004%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2005%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2006%' OR kaywords LIKE
 '%2007%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2008%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2009%' OR kaywords LIKE 
 '%2010%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2011%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2012%' OR kaywords LIKE
 '%2013%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2014%' OR kaywords LIKE '%2015%' OR kaywords LIKE
 '%2016%') AND type='2' AND state='0' AND price BETWEEN 79000 AND 10000000
```

Comment: А что вы под оптимизацией понимаете ? Никакая оптимизация невозможна в принципе когда используется like начинающийся на '%'. Потому как в этом случае в любом случае будет полный перебор таблицы (если конечно другие условия по индексу не отработают перед этим). По хорошему набор ключевых слов должен быть в отдельной таблице, что бы на четкое равенство (причем ID слов) сравнивать

Comment: Структуру таблицы покажите. И если окажется, что её проектировщик не предусмотрел отдельного поля (полей) для года (годов) - пути оптимизации очевидны...

Comment: вот https://yadi.sk/i/eKp3yY4ZvGeBo    заранее спосибо

Comment: года пишутся в формате 1985-1997

Comment: все я все сделал спасибо за советы